# systemctl daemon-reload issue

Tags: cron

Since a last update, I get the follow message every day via mail:

> /etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
>   Warning: Unit file of apache2.service changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.

I tried to do `systemctl daemon-reload` of course (!), but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried restarting Apache? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Also, this seems to be on topic https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=160476 as does this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=154758

Answer (score 1):

> Also, this seems to be on topic http://raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=160476

My take away from that is it is an annoying but inconsequential bug.  Presuming it starts upstream (with Apache or Debian) it should be fixed in not very long (it may even be so already -- update often).

It presumably triggers via `logrotate` because that restarts Apache.  You could remove Apache's logrotate file if you are fine with attending to that manually, or you could edit it or create your own that restarts Apache directly (via SIGHUP or `httpd restart`) rather than using the service.  I don't know if this will have more serious consequences, but if you are confident enough with it it is worth a try.

Comment: I still get this bug.